# Ошибка при компиляции С# проекта в IDE Rider на Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, nuget

Использую фреймворк для кросс-платформенных программ Eto.Forms

При компиляции проекта происходит такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: слишком мало информации, чтобы сказать что-то определённое. Код ошибки не ноль -- значит, произошла какая-то ошибка при работе nuget.exe.  По MSB3073 есть и [ответы на en so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914339/error-msb3073-how-do-i-fix-this) -- но причин много и все разные, есть и на [форуме майкрософт](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c14fd1c-4c6c-4a5b-ac2a-05a2972036e9/problem-in-running-build-error-msb3073?forum=tfsbuild).

Comment: Может быть ошибка из-за не соответствия версии фреймворка? В заголовке `Eto.WinForms - net45`, а `NuGet.Targets ... --runtime=v.4.0.30319`

Comment: Есть очень похожая на вашу ошибку здесь: [NuGet Package restore exited with code -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314880/nuget-package-restore-exited-with-code-1)